# How can i call cat_name from the cat_id of my choosing? MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Below i made a MySQL Table in my phpmyadmin.

[image]

I want to print on my php page the cat_name of a cat_id of my choosing. What code would i use exactly for that? I am looking at [this guide here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) But i am not figuring it out completely maybe someone can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: `SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE cat_id=5`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `WHERE` clause for this. Basically what it does is it filters the records you want.

```
SELECT Cat_Name
FROM category
WHERE CAt_ID = 1   -- place the value of your desired category id
```

Comment: Aren't sql queries case-sensitive? (fields names)

Answer (score 0):

is that so complicate??

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yourtablename WHERE cat_id='yourcatidhere' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  print_r($row);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $cat_id = isset($_POST['cat_id'])? (int)$_POST['cat_id']: 0;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE cat_id = '$cat_id'");
        $cat_name = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    }
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    Category ID: <input type="text" name="cat_id" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Category Name" />
</form>

<?php echo isset($cat_name)? $cat_name: ''; ?>
```

Comment: How can i make it so i dont need a submit form?